# 2 strings in one column, want to add the strings to a preexisting value

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which contains the goals and assists for teams in Spain. my problems is that some of the players played for 2 teams within a season and these are represented by the rows which contain 2 strings. due to this, python thinks these values are represent a new club but that's not the case, they moved from one club (the first string) to a new club (the second string).

How can i add the values of the second string to the clubs they are actually now representing, instead of making it look like its a new club ?

```
    year   country                        club        goals     assists
     2020    Spain                           Alaves     35       21
617  2020    Spain             Alaves,Athletic Club      0        0
618  2020    Spain                   Alaves,Granada      0        1
619  2020    Spain                    Athletic Club     42       31
620  2020    Spain    Athletic Club,Real Valladolid      1        0
621  2020    Spain                  Atletico Madrid     65       53
622  2020    Spain          Atletico Madrid,Osasuna      0        5
623  2020    Spain         Atletico Madrid,Valencia      0        0
624  2020    Spain                        Barcelona     80       51
625  2020    Spain                 Barcelona,Getafe      2        2
626  2020    Spain                            Cadiz     32       16
627  2020    Spain                   Cadiz,Valencia      1        0
628  2020    Spain                       Celta Vigo     55       37
629  2020    Spain       Celta Vigo,Real Valladolid      1        3
630  2020    Spain                            Eibar     25       17
631  2020    Spain                    Eibar,Sevilla      4        3
632  2020    Spain                            Elche     33       25
633  2020    Spain                           Getafe     24       11
634  2020    Spain                Getafe,Villarreal      1        1
635  2020    Spain                          Granada     46       29
636  2020    Spain                          Levante     46       35
637  2020    Spain                          Osasuna     36       21
638  2020    Spain                       Real Betis     50       33
639  2020    Spain                      Real Madrid     63       52
640  2020    Spain                    Real Sociedad     56       36
641  2020    Spain            Real Sociedad,Sevilla      1        2
642  2020    Spain                  Real Valladolid     33       20
643  2020    Spain                        SD Huesca     33       23
644  2020    Spain                          Sevilla     51       35
645  2020    Spain                         Valencia     48       35
646  2020    Spain                       Villarreal     57       33
```

Comment: Can we assume that you are using the Pandas library?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "how can i add the values of the second string to the clubs they are actually now representing, instead of making it look like its a new club ?"  Please update your question with an example of what you mean?  For example, Do you only want the second team to be represented, both teams represented, how do you want the goals and games to be split?

Comment: Maybe optimize your dataframes and use foreign keys to ensure you will have only one string (btw could you show a snippet of this dataset that hase "2 strings"?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, you can remove the first team with:

```
df['current_club'] = df['club'].apply(lambda s: s.split(',')[-1])
```

This will create a new column with just the current club where the player is playing.
Then you can run your analysis (grouping by team etc) using that new column without double teams.